# How to achieve Ejabberd_Clustering

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I thank you for spending your time to read my question. I am creating an application based on Ejabberd, it was written in Erlang. And now I need to implement the fault tolerant by using the clustering concept in Ejabberd. I followed [here](http://chad.ill.ac/post/35967173942/easy-ejabberd-clustering-guide-mnesia-mysql%22here%22) but I can't achieve the clustering concept. If i stop/crash one of my server (ie) master or slave, the other one didn't continue the process ie) it won't reconnect the stopped server. I used the authentication database in MySQL.

Comment: Are you expecting that the remaining server will restart the crashed server?

Comment: nope.. For an ex, I am login with 1 credential which is in SQL database is connected in main server, And I setup the cluster by the above link. once the main server crashed the credential also failed to login. I am expecting once the main server crashed then the remaining server will handle the credential. It wont affect the credential.

Comment: I'm still not understanding what you're saying. You have SQL credentials, and the second server cannot connect to the SQL database using those credentials? Or you have credentials stored inside of the SQL database and these no longer work?

Comment: yes i am facing the problem with first one which your'e mentioned.  I have SQL credentials, and the second server cannot connect to the SQL database using those credentials

Comment: The link you've got is about Mnesia. What code are you actually running?

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot I am confused about my thought whether my thought is correct or not can you guide me about it?

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot I also having the same issue like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796571/ejabberd-clustering-understanding

Comment: Your question is about some code that you've written, but you are not showing this code.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot I didn't write any code for achieve this. I just follow http://chad.ill.ac/post/35967173942/easy-ejabberd-clustering-guide-mnesia-mysql.