# Ejabberd Clustering understanding

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

Let assume I have `two ejabberd server` consider `X` and `Y` which has the same source and i did ejabberd clustering for those server by using [this](http://chad.ill.ac/post/35967173942/easy-ejabberd-clustering-guide-mnesia-mysql). Now consider `A` and `B` are user and those are connected in `X server`. Both A and B are in `ONLINE` state and those are connected via `X server`. If suppose X server is get `shutdown` or `crashed` by some issue. In this sceneraio whether the `A` and `B` are get `OFFLINE` state or `A` and `B` are in `ONLINE` state which is handle by `Y` server. I don't know whether my thought is right or not. If any one give me the suggestion about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nodes in different physical locations, you should set them up as separate clusters (even if it's a cluster of 1 node) and federate them. Clustering should only be done at datacenter level since there are mnesia transactional locks between all nodes in a cluster (e.g. creating a MUC room).

Comment: In this situation, once server X crashed it would break the socket connections of both A and B and server Y would eventually see that server X is down (after a certain time). When Y deemed that server X is down, it would clean up all sessions on that node so A and B sessions would be considered OFFLINE and any online friends of theirs would be sent an 'unavailable' presence stanza. Clients A and B, after seeing their socket connection broken would need to relog (into Y) to reestablish service.

Answer (score 0):

"Load balancing" is not what you are describing in your question.

In load balancing, a incoming connections are distributed in a balanced fashion over multiple nodes. This is so that no one server has too high a load (hence the name "load balancing"). It also provides fail-over capability if your load balancer is smart enough to detect and remove dead nodes.

A smart load balancer can make it so that *new* connections always succeed as long as there is at least one working node in your cluster. However, in your question, you talk about clients "maintaining the connection". That's something quite different.

To do that, you'd either need the connection to be stateless or you'd need each client to connect to all nodes. That's not how XMPP works: it's a stateful connection to a single server. You must rely on your clients to reconnect if they get disconnected.

Comment: I edited my question can you give me your suggestion about it?

Comment: You've made your question more clear, but the answer remains the same: you do not appear to understand some of the foundational concepts at work here.